# Not able to stop Azure SQL MI

Tags: azure

I am trying to stop one of our SQL MI but it gives below error
Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'You cannot stop the instance that has running operation on an instance or on one or more of its databases. Please wait for ongoing operation to finish or cancel ongoing operation, then try again.'

when tried to find ongoing operation using Get-AzSqlInstanceOperation it returns nothing.

I checked in sys.dm_operation_status  and can see 2 operations are CANCEL_IN_PROGRESS state for last 3 days and seems like it's stuck. tried all options but no luck.

Any idea how I can restart my MI forcefully ?

Thanks

tried Azure portal and Powershell both and it didn't work.

looking for some next level of help

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the ISO/ANSI SQL _language_. Instead you can add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1339338/how-to-do-a-forced-restart-on-a-sql-managed-instan), there is no option to force a restart of an Azure SQL Managed Instance. You must wait until the cancel operation is completed.

Answer (score 0):

[Stop and Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/instance-stop-start-how-to?view=azuresql-mi&tabs=azure-portal) an Azure SQL Managed Instance is still in preview. It is not possible to restart sql managed instance forcebly.
There is only a [User-Initiated Failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/user-initiated-failover?view=azuresql), which does not guarantee a SQL MI Instance restart.

```
$ResourceGroup = 'enter resource group of your MI'
$ManagedInstanceName = 'enter MI name'
Invoke-AzSqlInstanceFailover -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $ManagedInstanceName
```

For more information you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1339338/how-to-do-a-forced-restart-on-a-sql-managed-instan)